# Rails ActiveStorage unable to remove images on the localhost due to wrong path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

I'm working with `ActiveStorage` and I'm able to upload images and display without issue but unable to purge or deleted one of the images.

Here is the controller code:

```
          def photo_upload
            @images = @tool.images
          end

          def delete_image_attachment 
            @images = ActiveStorage::Attachment.find(params[:id])
            @images.purge
            redirect_back(fallback_location: request.referer)
          end


        private
        def set_tool
          @tool = Tool.find(params[:id])
        end

        def is_authorised
          redirect_to root_path, alert: "You don't have permission" unless current_user.id == @tool.user_id
        end

        def tool_params
          params.require(:tool).permit(:tool_type, :power_type, :accessories, :brand, :listing_name, :summary, :address, :is_machine, 

:is_hand, :is_cordless, :is_cord, :price, :active ,images: [])
            end

    end
```

...and the `.erb` files

```
<% if @tool.images.attached? %>

<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        Photo Display
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="row">
        <% @tool.images.each do |image| %>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="panel panel-default tools-gallery-panel">
                <div class="panel-heading preview ">
                    <%= link_to image_tag(image, class:"img-thumbnail tools-gallery"), image %>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <span class="pull-right">
                        <i class="fa fa-trash-o fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                       <%= link_to "Remove", delete_image_attachment_tool_path(image), method: :delete, data: {confirm: "Are you sure?"} %>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <% end %>
        <% end %>

    </div>
```

I get an error as it's a wrong ID as it linked to tools_id to a user ID, I am bit lost, I hope you can pinpoint the error

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sound like you have a `before_action :set_tool`, add the option `except: :delete_image_attachment`

```
before_action :set_tool, except: :delete_image_attachment
```

Comment: Oh my god, it's work as I add the ":delete_image_attachment" on the 
 before_action :set_tool, except: [:index, :new, :create,:delete_image_attachment] so embarssed right now